# Significato dell'espressione "da pastasciutta"

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Più tardi passarono due guardacaccia. –  Sempre lì che aspetta il cane, Signoria! Ma se l'ho visto al padiglione, in buone mani... 
>        – Come? 
>        – Ma sì, la Marchesa, ossia la Duchessa vedova (noi la chiamiamo Marchesa perché era Marchesina da ragazza) gli faceva tante feste come l'avesse sempre avuto. È un cane **da pastasciutta**, quello, mi lasci dire, Signoria. Ora ha trovato da star nel morbido e ci resta...

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "da pastasciutta" in questo passaggio? Ho cercato alla voce "pastasciutta" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla che possa avere senso in questo contesto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un **cane da pastasciutta** è un cane abituato alle comodità, a vivere a stretto contatto con le persone, che ha perso la sua indole "selvatica".

Infatti il termine pastasciutta indica un alimento di cui normalmente un cane non si ciba e indica che viene coccolato dai padroni.

Su Treccani si può anche trovare per [cane](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cane1/) con significato simile:

> c. da pagliaio, propr. il cane che fa la guardia alla casa del
>   contadino, ma più spesso con uso estens., cane di poco valore

La stessa espressione viene usata con un significato simile in questo passaggio tratto da [*Il pane sotto la neve* di Vanessa Navicelli](https://books.google.it/books?id=F8dVDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=cane%20da%20pastasciutta&source=bl&ots=Pp2M83MSmF&sig=87mDnQsGK71LWIIztrzO9ARn338&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjExbytg9DaAhWH1SwKHVy0Chw4ChDoAQhIMAk#v=onepage&q=cane%20da%20pastasciutta&f=false):

> Tino dà un'occhiata al cane; si sta stiracchiando le zampe anteriori
>   e poi ci riappoggia su il muso, socchiudendo gli occhi placido.
>          Tino scuote la testa. «È venuto da noi a dormire. È proprio un cane da
>   pastasciutta!»

Un'altra espressione simile, cambiando animale ma non significato, è **gatto da poltrona**.